ValueError in django project
i am creating a student login page and getting the error below, and to my surprise the same code for adminlogin works perfect. I am new to django
ValueError at /studentlogin/
The view myapp.views.studentlogin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/studentlogin/
Django Version: 5.0.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view myapp.views.studentlogin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Hardip Gajjar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 332, in check_response
Raised during:  myapp.views.studentlogin
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Hardip Gajjar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.2
Python Path:    
['E:\\KantamEducation',
 'E:\\KantamEducation',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm2023.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\Hardip '
 'Gajjar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Hardip Gajjar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Hardip Gajjar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Hardip Gajjar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
 'C:\\Users\\Hardip '
 'Gajjar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm2023.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Tue, 23 Apr 2024 11:56:21 +0530

views.py
def studentlogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            user = Student.objects.get(
                email=request.POST['email'],
                password=request.POST['password']
            )
            request.session['email'] = user.email
            request.session['fname'] = user.fname
            return render(request, 'studentindex.html')
        except:
            msg = 'Invalid Email or Password'
            return render(request, 'studentlogin.html',{'msg':msg})

student login HTML form
{% extends 'header.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


 
<!-- Admin Login Page Start -->
 
  <section class="section admin" data-section="section6" >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="section-heading">
            <h2>Student Login</h2>
          </div>
        <div class="section-heading">
              {% if msg %}
                  <b style="font-size: 15px;color: antiquewhite;">{{msg}}</b>
              {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <form type="POST" method ="post" id="studentlogin" action="{% url 'studentlogin' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}    
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <fieldset>
                      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required="">
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required="">
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <fieldset>
                  <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="button">Login</button>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<!--Admin Login Page Ends-->
    
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

i am new to django.
while same code for admin account works fine, views.py code for admin:
def adminlogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            user = Creator.objects.get(
                email=request.POST['email'],
                password=request.POST['password']
            )
            request.session['email'] = user.email
            request.session['fname'] = user.fname
            return render(request, 'adminindex.html')
        except:
            msg = "Invalid Username And Password"
            return render(request, 'adminlogin.html', {'msg': msg})
    else:
        return render(request, 'adminlogin.html')


You aren't handling the case where the request is not a POST request.
